# Java 8 Lambdas - equivalent of c# OfType

Tags: java, c#, java-8, lambda

I am learning the new java 8 features now, after 4 years exclusively in C# world, so lambdas are on top for me. I am now struggling to find an equivalent for C#'s "OfType" method.

What I have is a List myNodes , I want to get a List out of it, where Node is an interface, and SpecificNode is implementing it.

In C# it would be

```
IList<INode> myNodes = new List<INodes>(){new SpecificNode(), new OtherNode()}
IList<SpecificNode> specificNodes = myNodes.OfType<SpecificNode>()
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is **no exact** match in Java for the `.OfType<T>()` method, but you can use the Java8's filtering features:

```
IList<INode> myNodes = new ArrayList<INode>();
myNodes.add(new SpecificNode());
myNodes.add(new OtherNode());

List<SpecificNode> filteredList = myNodes.stream()
                                         .filter(x -> x instanceof SpecificNode)
                                         .map(n -> (SpecificNode) n)
                                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want to get of the explicit cast, you can do:

```
List<SpecificNode> filteredList = myNodes.stream()
                                             .filter(SpecificNode.class::isInstance)
                                             .map(SpecificNode.class::cast)
                                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You just need a `.map(n -> (SpecificNode) n)` between the filter and the collector.

Comment: Thanks! It works, even if the entire construct is much longer then in C#, and thats a real pity ;(

Comment: @PetrOsipov, I am almost sure it can be shortened. I will research about that more. :)

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue.  This is what I came up with, but since java doesn't do extension methods (maybe in 10 more years?), it is a static method.  This is using the stream API, though there isn't a particular reason you *must* do that.  The same basic checks would work just fine in a `for` loop with a preallocated ArrayList.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T> List<T> ofType(Class<?> out, List<Object> list) {
    return list.stream().filter(x -> out.isAssignableFrom(x.getClass()))
               .map(x -> (T) x) // unchecked
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

// fyi this code uses "boon" library
List<Object> objlist = list("ABC", 3, "def", -30.39); 
puts("strings=", ofType(String.class, objlist));  // strings= [ABC, def] 
puts("integers=", ofType(Integer.class, objlist)); // integers= [3]
```

Here is the version that doesn't use streams.  It works just the same, but some of the fun with streams is that ... you might be able to stream them, if thats your kind of thing.  I don't find it  useful very often except for helpers like this.

```
private static <T> List<T> ofType(Class<?> out, List<Object> list) {
    List<T> outList = new ArrayList<T>(list.size());
    for(Object o : list) {
        if ( out.isAssignableFrom(o.getClass())) {
            outList.add((T)o);
        }
    }
    return outList;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a Function containing the Stream pipeline, which reduces its invocation.

```
    Function<List<INode>,List<SpecificNode>> ofSub =
       bl -> bl.stream()
               .filter(x -> x instanceof SpecificNode)
               .map(n -> (SpecificNode) n)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For instance:

```
    for( SpecificNode s: ofSub.apply( myNodes ) ){
         //...
    }
```

Comment: Definitely an option. Is there an equivalent of c#'s extension methods in java? might be easier to do with them if existing...

Comment: Trying to find feature f of language X in language Y is usually not the best approach. Beyond the trivial, each language provides (more or less) orthogonal sets of functions. Languages trying to cram everything in suffer from overweight.

Comment: @PetrOsipov: It took Java years to catch up to C# on lambdas - it will be years more before it has extension methods, if at all. Java cannot be extended as quickly as C#.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of first filtering and then mapping the stream to the desired target type, it is possible to do both in a single call to the stream via `flatMap` and this small helper function:

```
private static <Target extends Base, Base> Function<Base, Stream<Target>> ofType(Class<Target> targetType) {
    return value -> targetType.isInstance(value) ? Stream.of(targetType.cast(value)) : Stream.empty();
}
```

This `Function` basically checks for a element if a cast is possible and then casts it, returning a stream with the single casted element or an empty stream if the cast was not possible.

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3, "Hallo", 4, 5, "Welt")
    .flatMap(ofType(String.class))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

With the help of a `flatMap` operation all returned streams can be  concatenated.

I assume that a separated check and cast are easier to understand and maybe even faster in execution, this is just a prove of concept for a single stream operation.

Comment: The best answer. Not understood why it's so underrated

Comment: @DenisItskovich Because it is much slower then .filter().map(). It requires to create and concatenate lots of temporary streams. The method mapMulti (since Java 16) probably performs better, but I did not try it yet.

Comment: @niks Did you check the performance? As I wrote in my answer, it may be possible that it is slower, but it's also possible that the cost of creating some minimal `Stream` instances (as returned by `Stream.of` and `Stream.empty`) is negligible compared to the cost of checking and casting all the instances.

Comment: @LukasKörfer Yes I did. I've come up with the very same idea myself when I was searching for an equivalent for the C# OfType<T>() and it turned out that it is too slow  (copared to filter().map()) to be used in productive code.

Answer (score 0):

FYI Java 16 introduces `mapMulti`, which is claimed to be faster than [the `flatMap` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48424505/43534) in the Java docs, although at least one implementation internally calls `flatMap`, so I am somewhat dubious.  I have not tested its performance, but being a one-liner at point of use is attractive.

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3, "Hallo", 4, 5, "Welt")
    .mapMulti(ofType(String.class))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

```
public static <T, U> BiConsumer<T, Consumer<U>> ofType(final Class<U> clazz) {
    return (obj, consumer) -> {
        if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass())) {
            consumer.accept(clazz.cast(obj));
        }
    };
}
```